# How to change the layout DPI for PDF export in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts, pdf, dpi

I am working with QGIS 3.28.4. I have set the export resolution to 300dpi in the layout properties but when I export the layout as a PDF it gets exported at 72dpi. If I export it as png it gets exported at 300dpi. How can I resolve this and make sure the PDF gets exported at 300dpi?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the environment variable `GDAL_PDF_DPI` helps (<kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Options...</kbd> > <kbd>System</kbd> > <kbd>Environment</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: It worked Thanks